# C# Wait until the object has been inserted to the list (freeze application)

Tags: c#

I have stumbled upon an annoying problem. I have a timer that foreach a list(Generics) every 250ms (1-5 objects in the list). And if it "meets" the criteria, it should add the object to an "ignore list". But the problem is that sometimes it doesn't add the object to the ignore list and therefore letting it through (even if it 250ms ago should have added it).

So my question is, what the best way to make sure that the loop freezes until the object has been added to the list (Now everything is running on the main thread)?

```
 // this method is called every 250ms
 void check()
 {
    foreach (GetAll g in GetAllInList)
    {
       InIgnoreList(g);
    }
 }
 // InIgnoreList(g)
 void InIgnoreList(g)
 {
    foreach(var b in g.List())
    {
       if(IgnoreList.Exists(x => x.Name == g.Name))
       break;

       // New method where I add it, but sometimes the IgnoreList.Exists Check lets it
        through
    }

 }
```

Thanks :)

Comment: What's `x`? What do you do with `b`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you're encountering a race condition - it may be that `check()` is being called before the last call to `check()` has actually finished.

If you do something like this it would eliminate the race condition...

```
readonly object lockObject = new Object();

void check()
{
    lock (lockObject)
    {
        foreach (GetAll g in GetAllInList)
        {
            InIgnoreList(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use `lock` in combination with a `bool` flag to determine if the `check()` method is still running before calling it when the timer event fires.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, but it worked, but I had to use it on both loops. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the timer before calling your `check()` code (or at the beginning of `check()`, as it's not clear what the context is here), and enable it when `check()` returns (or at the end of `check()`). This stops the timer from being fired again before the code completes.